# Undefined Namespace in Argo UI deployed using Helm when launched first time

Tags: kubernetes-helm, argo-workflows, argo, argo-events

We have deployed argoworkflow and argoevents using helm packages.
After successful deployment when the argo UI is launched first time using secret token which is generated for the SA configured.
Once logged in the UI the namespace is filled as **undefined**.

[image]

But once it is changed manually to something else like argo-events which contains some workflow-templates, it referesh and we can now see the list of workflow-templates.

Is there a way to configure in helm templates, so that the namespace can be set as workflow-templates by default instead of undefined.

Comment: Usually you'd specify a namespace with a `helm install -n` option, though nothing stops you from putting a `metadata: { namespace: }` field in your template files.  Is any part of your chart relevant to this?  Is there a programming-related question, or are you just trying to configure ArgoCD?

Comment: @DavidMaze This is regarding configuring ArgoWorklow , 
While installing the helm chart for argoworkflow we are configuring the namespace and can see the pods under same NS. But in UI not sure why it is showing as undefined